# Present and past participle in same sentence

Tags: tenses

Is anything wrong about this phrase "We build software solutions designed for scalability"?
I think there is, because the tenses are not consistent.

Comment: Designed is not acting as a verb.

Comment: @Noah Sure it is. It just isn’t a finite one.  Participles, gerunds, and infinitives can all introduce verbal phrases in English, which makes them verbs, verbs that just happen to function as substantives or modifiers. Consider: “Finishing it early is what makes me happiest”; the direct object of *finishing* is *it*, and only verbs have direct objects, so *finishing* is without question a verb.  It is also acting as a substantive here. You can do the same with the other non-finite forms.

Comment: @tchrist- I thought participles were not acting as verbs. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing whatsoever wrong with that sentence. A participle that introduces a verbal phrase is under no obligation to agree with the tense of the main verb. That just would not be sensible.

Examples of the past participle used with non-past verbs:

- We**’re looking** for people ***interested*** in birding.
- English **is** the world language ***spoken*** by the most number of individuals as a second language.
- I **won’t fix** a roof ***damaged*** by hail.
- You **should drink** only water ***boiled*** for at least one minute.
- ***Broken*** windows **must be repaired** immediately.

Examples of the present participle used with non-present verbs:

- I **saw** you ***sleeping*** in the park.
- I always **ate** my ice cream with it ***dripping*** down my chin.
- I **didn’t want** him ***contemplating*** any other possibility.
- ***Running*** in the morning **was** never my passion.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing whatsoever wrong with explaining why the sentence is fine. It is obviously for what reason he's unsure about the correctness of his sentence, so why don't say a few words about it if you really want to answer that question...

Comment: @Em1 I have noticed that a lot of experienced users on this site answer the question first and then elaborate on it via a series of edits. It's oddly entertaining watching some of them punch in their edits before SE decides that it has been too long and a new revision is warranted. As you can probably tell, that's what tchrist has done so here as well :)

Comment: @coleopterist Because I only ever seem to gain reputation for accepted answers, not for merely upvoted ones, I often come back and improve the original. :) [yes, I know why]

Answer (score 5):

*Designed for scalability* is a participle clause, postmodifying *solutions*. *Designed* is a non-finite verb, which means it shows no tense or person. The clause can be replaced with a finite  relative clause with a passive verb: *We build software solutions that are designed for scalability*. That may help you understand why there is no inconsistency in the verbs.